# Add a dropdown box using Laravel + Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How do I add a dropdown box onto my current Blade code?

This is what I currently have:

```
{!! Form::input('text', 'example', old("example", $user->example), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S', array('id' => 'your_id', 'class' => 'your_class'));
```

where:

`size`: name of dropdown,

`array`: array to generate dropdown,

`S`: default selected value,

After that you can pass `id`, `class`, `style` in an array like:

```
array('id' => 'your_id', 'class' => 'your_class')
```